# How to find status (on/off) of any applicance ( light, fan, etc.) connected to an electrical circuit

Tags: sensor, voltage-detector

There are 4 appliances connected to an electric circuit, how to determine which applicance is on/off and pass that information to an electronic device in binary form.

The idea is to make an electronic device which when attached to the electrical circuit determines whether the applicance is switched on or not and pass the information in binary format

Comment: The "appliance" should have some kind of indication of it's status, obviously.

Comment: You would measure the current.

Comment: The simplest acceptable solution will be a standard rectifier and optocoupler circuit for each appliance. Google mains detection.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. CR-Magnetics [CR2550](http://www.crmagnetics.com/remote/cr2550) current indicator.*

> The CR2550 series Remote Current Indicators are a low cost method for providing a visual indication of electrical current flow. The indicators are factory calibrated to provide a preset turn-on point. The value of the turn-on point is determined by the customer and specified in the part number. Attached to the transformer is a high efficiency, bi-polar LED that illuminates when the current is above the turn-on point. The indicator is available as standard with 11 inch long leads and a red LED indicator. designed as a low cost method for providing a visual indication of electrical current flow. The current-carrying wire is routed through the window opening in the current sensing transformer. Attached to the transformer is a high efficiency, bi-polar LED that illuminates when the current is above the turn-on point. The indicator is available as standard with an 11 inch long lead and a red or green LED indicator.

- Turn-on Point: 0.75 Aac RMS
- Maximum Continuous Rating: 20 Aac RMS
- Frequency: 50 to 400 Hz
- Operating Temperature Range: -30 C to +60 C
- Storage Temperature Range: -55 C to +85 C
- LED Indicator Type: Bi-polar, Red/Red or Green/Green
- LED Mounting Hardware: Plastic one-piece, press-in lens supplied

From the spec you can see that for this model you would need to get the ampere-turns through the coil to between 0.75 and 20 A when your load is on. For example, with a 0.25 A load you would need four or five turns of your current carrying conductor through the transformer to ensure reliable switch-on.

There are a few application notes on the linked page.

You can glue the LED to an LDR to signal to your micro-controller or remove the LED and replace it with the input of an opto-coupler.

[image]

*Figure 2. The CR-Magnetics devices use LEDs as shown on the right. If converting to an opto-isolator it would need the same LED arrangement internally.*

Note that the spec says the LEDs are *bi-polar* which means that there are [two back to back](http://lednique.com/leds-with-more-than-two-pins/) in the one package for AC.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Hall Effect sensor attached to the appliance power inputs. These are non-invasive sensors so you would not have to wire them into the circuit. Here is a popular one [from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8882). Many of these are analog, so you would have to set up an analog-digital converter or some sort of logic circuit to convert to binary.

EDIT: as pointed out in comments, you'll need to pull out one of the mains in order for this to work, otherwise the currents will cancel each other out.

Comment: The OP should be aware that they cannot just put the power cable through: the forward and return current cancel out in the sensor. Instead, the need to separate out one wire, preferably the hot wire but not the ground wire, and pass only that through.

Comment: Good to know, I was not aware of that limitation. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Non-Invasive Current Sensor like the one sparkfun has: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005